# Xamarin forms : UI freeze with this simple loop

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have software that receives data from hardware using FTDI. Attached is a simulation code.

Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsVisible="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Number}"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Id}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

**First attempt:**

running the code, after a while I get around 2000 entries, and then it freezes the screen.

```
public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
 }
public class MainViewModel
{
    Thread _background;
    int index = 0;
    public MainViewModel()
    {

        Items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

        _background = new Thread(AddItems);
        _background.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;

        _background.Start();
    }


    public void AddItems()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            List<Data> list = new List<Data>();

            Random r = new Random();

            for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
            {
                int value = r.Next();

                Data d = new Data()
                {
                    Id = index++,
                    Number = value
                };

                list.Add(d);
            }

      

            foreach (Data d in list)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    Items.Insert(0, d);
                });
            }
        }

    }

    public ObservableCollection<Data> Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

}

**Second attempt:**

Single call to BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Better, I get a list that is updated every now and then, and the update becomes faster and faster?!

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Thread _background;
    int index = 0;
    public MainViewModel()
    {

        Items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

        _background = new Thread(AddItems);
        _background.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;

        _background.Start();
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public void AddItems()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ObservableCollection<Data> list = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

            Random r = new Random();

            for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
            {
                int value = r.Next();

                Data d = new Data()
                {
                    Id = index++,
                    Number = value
                };

                list.Add(d);
            }


            var temp = new ObservableCollection<Data>(Items);

            foreach (Data d in list)
            {
                temp.Insert(0, d);
            }

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Items = temp;
            });

        }

    }

    private ObservableCollection<Data> _items;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Data> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
        }
    }
}
```

**Third attempt**

Added: Thread.Sleep(50);

Best, I can live with it...

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Thread _background;
    int index = 0;
    public MainViewModel()
    {

        Items = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

        _background = new Thread(AddItems);
        _background.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;

        _background.Start();
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public void AddItems()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ObservableCollection<Data> list = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

            Random r = new Random();

            for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++)
            {
                int value = r.Next();

                Data d = new Data()
                {
                    Id = index++,
                    Number = value
                };

                list.Add(d);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(50);

            var temp = new ObservableCollection<Data>(Items);

            foreach (Data d in list)
            {
                temp.Insert(0, d);
            }

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Items = temp;
            });

        }

    }

    private ObservableCollection<Data> _items;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Data> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
        }
    }
}
```

I guess that the problem is with BeginInvokeOnMainThread, too much work is done on the UI thread...but why it is freezes?

Can anyone explain the behavior? Why adding Sleep solve the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: **1)** If you don't want to freeze UI, then why set `_background.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;`? **2)** Adding items one at a time causes UI to attempt to update after each item. With many items, this will be very slow. **3)** `Sleep` gives UI a chance to do something, despite your higher-priority. **4)** Any technique you use, that involves a list with thousands of items, won't work well in Xamarin Forms, if the list is dynamically changing. You'll need to instead "page through" the items. Show some limited number at a time, then user presses a button to see next group of items.

Comment: If you need that priority to ensure data isn't lost, on *that* thread, only *queue* the items - don't display them. Either have a second thread, at a lower-priority, that updates the display, OR don't touch UI at all, until user presses some button.

Comment: In the real application I do have a blocking queue and 2 threads (now below normal), one enque the items and one deque and raise event to the view model  the view model create new collection from the items and rebind :   Data = newData  . still  it take about 50 seconds for the UI to display first items.

Comment: 50 seconds when there are how many items? Did you see my point #4 in first comment? If you have many items, don't add them all to the displayed list. Design a UI so user can "Page" through them, a limited number at a time.

Comment: More information : I am using d2xx.jar to get the data from ftdi device. I am getting 2 items each time and now I display only those 2 items, still I need to wait 50 seconds until i get first display (even though i do get events with data) after 50 seconds it is running ok

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason UI would hang for 50 seconds. Sounds like some code is running on UI thread, that should instead be on a background thread. Maybe start a [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch), and print the current stopwatch time at different places in code.

Comment: I get this in the output window  : [OpenGLRenderer] Davey!   ** duration=56141ms; ***  Flags=0......

Comment: No clue. You'll have to try different experiments, to isolate more narrowly what is wrong. For example, instead of calling the hardware, provide some hard-coded test data. Or comment out most of the code, see if it still hangs.